# Custom listview different on tablets than phones

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a listview that looks different on tablets than phones.  I have a layout-xlarge folder with a different list item layout than the one in the normal layout folder.  The tablet version has an imageview that the phone version does not.  The image to be placed in the imageview is not a drawable, it's downloaded from the internet so cannot set it before hand.

When I'm creating my custom adapter, while overriding getView, how would I set the image in the imageview that is not always there.  Obviously, it would have to be quick, since it's doing the check while scrolling.  Is there a way to determine if the program is running on a tablet, or if the view exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the imageview is not null ( then its a tablet) and download the image.

Comment: I looked into that, but I couldn't find a way to.  Wouldn't R.id.imageview be valid no matter what, it just wouldn't display on phones?  Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: R.id.imageView will be valid since it is a generated constant before compilation. But, findViewById(R.id.imageView) will be null since its not inflated on your phone.